# How to thread a flask app and function with a while loop to run simultaneously?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, flask

I have a flask app which I want to use with a while loop running in the background. My first thought was to use threading to run them at the same time. The problem I stumbled upon is that only the first thread works (whether the flask app or the function with while loop comes first). My code is:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target = app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)).start()
    Process(target = statupdate()).start()
```

Note: I also used the library "thread" and making the flask app its own function.

Is there some way to fix this error or run the two simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues:

- You are not threading in this case, you are multi-processing. It's something completely different but will still achieve what you seek.
- You are running the functions instead of giving them as a target.

In order to make this work, don't run the function:

```
Process(target=app.run, kwargs=dict(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)).start()
Process(target=statupdate).start()
```

Comment: For the problem, your answer was perfect because both functions are simultaneously working. However, my while loop in the function "statupdate", is not working or activating (the while loop opens, edits, and closes a file; file not updating). Any ideas why?

Comment: Nevermind, the problem is related to the file not updating with every iteration of the while loop. This is the right answer otherwise.